# Hibernate : Genereting dynamic entity at runtime

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to create entity based on information from database. Based on database I created string like this :

`   package az.com.ds.entity.crudEntity;

```
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Column;

@Table(name = "CMN_SP", schema = "CMN")
@Entity
public class CmnSpEnt {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

}  `
```

Then I created java file based on this string and compiled it at runtime. Everything works perfectly to this step. But when I want to get data based on entity it throws exception as

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: CmnSpEnt is not mapped [Select  x  from CmnSpEnt x ].

Now I need to map entity for hibernate in order to get data from database. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: try with sql native query. Or just try hql = "from CmnSpEnt"

Comment: I have a crud controller, which based on user's request it generates hql and gets data based on this. In this case i am doing the same, i am just telling my controller get all data from CmnSpEnt, but hibernate does not know CmnSpEnt, because i created it at runtime. And there will be no meaning if i used native sql, because in this case crud controller will not work. That is why i want to map runtime created entity for hibernate.